# Default HRESULT hResult = E_NOTIMPL?

Tags: c++, xaml, winapi, windows-ce

I am working on a win7 based system using silverlight for embedded for UI graphics and C++ for firmware. I have noticed that in many of the existing functions (written before i was brought onto the project), there is some code that i am not quite sure what it is doing.

```
HRESULT AddAlarm::AlarmType_SelectionChanged (IXRDependencyObject* pSender, XRSelectionChangedEventArgs* pArgs)
{
    HRESULT hResult = E_NOTIMPL;
    if((NULL == pSender)||(NULL==pArgs))
    {
      hResult = E_INVALIDARG;
    }
    //Code to set visibility of UI elements
   if(index ==0) //index is the threshold type index from the combobox. Can be 0-3.
   {
      m_pAlarmLowThreshold->SetVisibility(XRVisibility_Collapsed);
   }
   //Code repeats for other threshold types and visibility states.

 return hResult;
}
```

The if statement is pretty straightforward and the function returns hResult, but i dont understand the declaration **HRESULT hResult = E_NOTIMPL;**. It is declaring a variable of type HRESULT and assigning it a default HRESULT value of E_NOTIMPL, but since the function doesnt modify this value outside of the if statement, doesnt this mean that it remains as E_NOTIMPL, basically telling the system that it (something) is not implemented or is wrong?

Comment: Might be auto-generated code from a tool that the programmer used, that's very common for COM code.  Fairly unlikely it remains at E_NOTIMPL, that would be a bug that's easy to notice.  Particularly from Silverlight, it throws a NotImplementedException.

Comment: `"//Irrellavent code"` - only true if nowhere in said-bag-of-mysteries is there any chance of changing the value of `hResult`.

Answer (score 1):

I know that when this king of method is automatically generated trought the VS interface. The inside code is always something like

```
return E_NOTIMPL;
```

I think what your predecessors tried to do is beeing clean in there way to develop the method by assuring them self that all case are processed by starting with an E_NOTIMPL that should be changed during method's processing.

This kind of method should return *s_OK* when it works fine. Here is a list of possible codes :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378137%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

If there is no assigning of an S_OK it means indeed that the function is not fully implemented thus an E_NOTIMPL seems correct (or not :) )

Comment: In the class declaration for AddAlarm, there is this snippit of code: `static HRESULT GetXamlSource(__in XRXAMLSource*                            pXamlSource)                                                   
                  HRESULT hr = E_INVALIDARG;
       if(pXamlSource)
       {
        pXamlSource->SetResource(App:GetHInstance(), IDR_ADDALARM);
        hr = S_OK;
       }
       return hr;`

Does this have any relevance to the above code understanding since this is the only area within the class that deals with HRESULT

Comment: `E_NOTIMPL` is **never** correct, if a method is implemented. The `E_NOTIMPL` constant is reserved for reporting that a method is genuinely not implemented. For all other error modes pick a different return value, or define one if you are the author of an interface.